# Customize Url or Hide Query String using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new one, I learn `.htaccess`. I want to customize my URL
from 
`index.php?page=mobile`
to 
`index/page/mobile`

I used this code but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^index/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `^index/([^/.]+)/?$` won't match `index/page/mobile`. That expression only goes one level deep. Are you familiar with regexes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This rule should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cashearn/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index/page/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index/page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will let you have URL as `http://domain.com/index/page/mobile` on your page.

Comment: zohaib wants "index" also in url

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and what URL did you enter in browser?

Comment: This .htaccess file is located with index.php file

Comment: ok what is `xxxxxxx` here before `index.php`? Is this a folder?

Comment: yes folder its a web name which i run in localhost like localhost:1000/cashearn/index.php?page=mobile

Answer (score 2):

Try that code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index/page/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: **Dear downvoter, can you tell why did you downvoted my answer?**

Answer (score 0):

This should work - not tested though

```
RewriteRule ^index/page/([^/.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```