# Rerun or continue rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have some rewrites that will change file names to url structures.

http://example.com/landing-myfile.html will be converted to http://example.com/landing/myfile/

I'm trying to set a default page, keep the url and then reprocess the rules.

So if a user types in `http://example.com/asdfasdfasdf`

it will redirect to `http://example.com/landing-mydefault.html`

but i want it to show as `http://example.com/landing/mydefault/`

I have the rewrites working for all of the pretty URLs and I have missing folders/files redirecting to the default page. But then I need to continue rewriting for all of the other rules.

Here is what I have so far.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirects bad requests to a default.
#works but leavings landing-mydefault.html in the address bar.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /landing-mydefault.html [R,L]

#process the pages and converts them to pretty urls.
#everything below works as it should.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} landing-([^.]+)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /landing/%1/ [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} landing-([^.]+)\.html\?v=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /landing/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^landing/([^/]+)/?$ /landing-$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^landing/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /landing-$1.html?v=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rules in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ /landing/mydefault/ [R,L]

#redirects bad requests to a default.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^landing/ /landing/mydefault/ [R,L,NC]

#process the pages and converts them to pretty urls.
#everything below works as it should.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+landing-([^.]+)\.html\?v=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /landing/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+landing-([^.]+)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /landing/%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^landing/([^/]+)/?$ landing-$1.html [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^landing/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ landing-$1.html?v=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: seems no matter what is put into the address bar, even valid files, will return a webpage not available error.

Comment: you're the one that helped me write the pretty urls. [Here's the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784082/htaccess-url-rewrite-with-and-without-query-string)if it helps solve this. Thanks.

Comment: It will leave whatever was in the address bar.

Comment: Ok - so apparently my webserver had quit - which was why I was getting the webpage unavailables - but some were working due to cache. I tried your original update - which still didn't work. The updates listed above (currently) return a redirect loop. Also - landing-a.html and landing-b.html will both redirect to landing/mydefault/ even though they exists, with a redirect loop.

Comment: That seems to work for everything except the root level - which is just a list of files. There isn't an index page in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65294/discussion-between-anubhava-and-veo).