# Rewrite URL to hide query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to mask the query string of my pages in order to hide it's unique page ID. This is important as each ID needs to be unique to a user.

Currently the URL structure looks like this:

http://domain.com/page.php?Page_ID=1234
*(where 1234 is any number)*

but I need it to look like this:

http://domain.com/page.php

I have tried adding the following to the *.htaccess* file but it does not seem to make any difference:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page.php?Page_ID=([0-9]+)/$ page.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

I've looked at other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892542/customize-url-or-hide-query-string-using-htaccess) and others, but can't seem to find a solution. Is there something I might be missing here?

Comment: mod rewrite does not pass the query string, for that the condition needs to use [QUERY_STRING](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString). However you shouldn't be using mod rewrite to "mask" query parameters. If that is literally what you want to do, just don't include them in the link in the first place.

Comment: You should use POST method instead of GET. This is recommended for any information that must not be public.

Comment: Thanks @AD7six this was already done by the previous coder, so it's now my job to "mask" it. I was looking for a way to avoid going to PHP town, but looks like I might have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query string is not part of match in rewrite rule, you need to match against %{THE_REQUEST} using a rewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?page_ID=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks @starkeen this is the closest I have gotten. It did indeed change the URL to what i wanted, however I have an error.